# Odd react-native issue with rendering

Tags: react-native

I'm currently trying to learn react-native and running into a problem after a tutorial. I followed the PropertyFinder tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site, which went fine.

Breaking away now to start something on my own, I can't seem to get a page to render - and I keep running into the same exception which may be causing the page not to render (but I'm not entirely sure).

Here is the main app page, which is simply the navigator:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var WelcomePage = require('./WelcomePage');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var MyApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <React.NavigatorIOS style={styles.container} 
          initialRoute={{
          title: 'Welcome',
          component: WelcomePage
        }}/>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

And here's the welcome page:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    textTitle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 35,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    textSubs: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 25,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});

class WelcomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('About to render welcome page');
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.textTitle}>
                    Welcome to MyApp!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.textSubs}>
                    Good Choice for an App
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.textSubs}>
                    Going to start with setting up the App
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.textSubs}>
                    Are you ready?
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = WelcomePage;
```

Now, the console logging comes out correctly with 'About to render welcome page', however the result I get is just a blank white window. If I use the chrome debugger, I do get an exception if a chose to Pause on Exceptions. The code snippet it pauses on is this:

```
/**
 * Given a constructor can we call it without `new`?
 *
 * @param {function} Collection
 */
function isCallableWithoutNew(Collection) {
  try {
    Collection();  // <<<--- Here's where the exception seems to happen
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

If I go back to the tutorial project, it works just fine.
The only difference I can see is that when I initialized the tutorial project, the Animation library I pulled in did not have an 'Experimental' version (RCTAnimation), but with the new project I tried to start above, I have to use the Experimental version if I want it to work. Really though, I only tested that early on and am not pulling it in any longer (I don't need it yet).

I've also tried playing around a bit with the styles, but get the same result - and the same exception occurring.

Exception stack chrome shows is:

```
"TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new'
    at Map (native)
    at isCallableWithoutNew (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:15407:5)
    at shouldPolyfillES6Collection (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:15378:5)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:14500:8
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:15095:3
    at require (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:245:25)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:14288:11
    at require (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:245:25)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:14131:11
    at require (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle:245:25)"
```

I want to say that looks like an API version issue or something?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the stack trace for the IsCallableWithoutNew call?

Comment: Sorry just got time to do that - I added it to the post above.

Comment: Well I find that the same exception occurs on the tutorial project that works!  Very odd... So it's got to be something with my styles and JSX.

Answer (score 2):

So this ended up being my styles on the 'index.ios.js' page.

I changed this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

To this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

And the view then rendered.
I guess I need to spend some time on figuring out how these styles layout components...

If anyone knows why the main NavigatorIOS pane would push content too far off to the right to be visible (which is what was happening) if the styles were set as they were originally, please let me know.

The culprits were:
'justifyContent'
'alignItems'

'backgroundColor' of course had no affect on the view rendering (I didn't add it back in but could without issue).

Comment: I am also confused by why making flex:1 as the only style will make the render work...